# Logging console output using Qt Installer Framework scripting

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I added some console.log("xxxxxx") via component / controller scripting to my installer.

ie.

```
function Controller()
{
    console.log("OS: " + systemInfo.productType);
}
```

How can I view the console log during the running of the installer?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if you can see a log during installation. But after a "successful" installation the `TargetDir` will contain a file named `InstallationLog.txt` that contains all the `console.log` lines from the installation process.

Edit: To see it live, do like @CherryDT points out in his comment: Run your installer from the command line and provide the `-v` parameter (fx `my_installer.exe -v`).

Edit: The previous Edit is slightly wrong, check @KcFnMi answer.

Comment: It should be possible to see the log "live" when running the installer with `-v` from a terminal.

Comment: Here on Windows I only get console output at runtime when doing `setup.exe --verbose`, `setup.exe -v` prints nothing. why?

Answer (score 1):

To see [console.log](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-console.html) information at runtime (the time you're running the installer, not the time you are building the installer) do:

```
installer.exe -d
```

or

```
installer --version
```

> -d, --verbose Verbose mode. Prints out more information.

https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-cli.html

Note: It's **not** `-v`:

> -v, --version Displays version information.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, they must have changed it. Probably when they moved from IFW 3 to 4. It used to be `-v` for `verbose`. At least in version 3 of the IFW this `-v` is still the way to get verbose information